# Inserting empty variables into MySQL with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm banging my head against a wall, trying to work out why this PDO prepared statement isn't working. The only thing I can conclude is that if a variable is empty, the INSERT fails, but this is confusing because I must've done this a thousand times before without issue.

Here's my code. All of the variables are being set from an POST variable, so some of them could be blank if the user didn't provide this data.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO students
    (id, classid, userid, firstname, surname, form, gender)
    VALUES ('', :classid, :userid, :firstname, :surname, :form, :gender)");

    $stmt->execute(array(':userid' => $userid, ':classid' => $classid, ':firstname' => $firstname, ':surname' => $surname, ':form' => $form, ':gender' => $gender));
```

Is there some way of telling it to insert an empty  field if the variable is empty?

EDIT: To be clear, this is not a new statement. I had previously been INSERTing with unprepared MySQLi, and had only just got around to updating this bit of code to PDO.

EDIT 2: My schema:

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment  
encryption  int(1)  NO              
classid int(11) NO              
googleclassroom varchar(50) NO              
userid  varchar(50) NO              
firstname   varchar(100)    NO              
surname varchar(100)    NO              
form    varchar(10) NO              
gender  varchar(10) NO              
colour_code varchar(10) NO              
col1    varchar(50) NO              
col2    varchar(50) NO              
col3    varchar(50) NO              
col4    varchar(50) NO              
col5    varchar(50) NO              
col6    varchar(50) NO              
col7    varchar(50) NO              
timestamp   datetime    NO
```

Comment: What do you man by not working? Are you getting any error? Can you log SQL exception?

Comment: Is it possible to insert values when user provides all values?

Comment: It's not inserting the row. There's no error, but I'm not sure I've got it set up to report errors.

Comment: @Billa If I enclose the $variables in quotation marks (in other words, turn them into values), it inserts fine

Comment: Allow your db to accept nulls?

Comment: @Jixone I assume it is accepting nulls. If I replace a $variable with '', that will also INSERT.

Comment: This is a statement that has been running in the code for many months successfully using unprepared MySQLi. It's only after converting it to a prepared statement that it's failing.

Comment: Your issue is when a user choose not to enter anything to the filed and leave it blank and when the empty variable get hit the SQL it throws an error saying something is empty. So now you want over come that right ?

Comment: @Sand Yes (well, no error is thrown that I can see, but it doesn't insert)

Comment: By the way, if I attempt a similar thing using the statement builder in PHPMyAdmin, I get a similar problem. That also won't let me insert prepared variables that are empty

Comment: Can you update your question with your schema for `students`?

Comment: I don't know how you hand over the form data to the PHP but if you're using AJAX or other in the middle it won't show you the SQL error you have to use the browser console to see it any way I'll try to post what I did when I faced a similar problem. It's not pretty but it works

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Done

Comment: @Sand I'm doing it over ajax, but monitoring the response in the console (there is no response, but as I mentioned earlier, I'm not totally sure how to get PDO to spit out errors anyway)

Comment: If you're in the console go to network there you might see the data hand over double click on it which will open the direct link in browser there you will get to see the error.

Comment: I still think it's my original answer see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc7760 click build schema.

Comment: $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: @Rob I'd go with a ternary operator and allow for NULL values; that I think would be your best bet. Or set a default (empty) value to the ternaries if you can't accept empty values in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments and answers. Several different users suggested allowing NULL values; @sand recommended I set the default value of these columns to NULL. It worked

I remain baffled as to how this has worked happily for months (using an unprepared MySQLi statement) but refused to accept these INSERTs from a PDO statement.

**Anyway, the answer (all credit to @Sand, @Anshuman and @Lawrence) is to set the default column values to NULL**, then it doesn't care if the variables are empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can check with following:

1. Allow all columns to accept `NULL`
2. If `id` is primary key, remove it from query. You can set it to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

EDIT:

As `id` is primary key in your schema, you can't set ''. Also it seems every column is not allowed to accept `NULL` and because user is not providing the value the variables like `$form` could be undefined or NULL so your INSERT statement won't execute.

EDIT 2:

Try to find out exact error. Whether it's for SQL or PHP.

You can set display error by using [link](http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/)

Comment: The reason I don't think this is the solution is that an identical MySQL query in the old code worked fine. Adding or removing the id field has no impact on whether this works. The only thing that stops it running is if I bind an empty variable.

The table certainly accepts NULL values, as thousands of rows with NULL values have been previously set.

Comment: can you set display error. here is the link how to set
http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/

Comment: Undefined offset: 12 in ...PATH... on line 83

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're having is due to your data getting bind as `bindParam()`. According to PHP doc's.

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark
>   placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the
>   statement.

So I like to suggest using `bindValue()` instead. To explain why I'm referring back to PHP manual.

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference
>   and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is
>   called.

So my answer would be,

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO students
    (classid, userid, firstname, surname, form, gender)
    VALUES (:classid, :userid, :firstname, :surname, :form, :gender)");

$stmt->bindValue(':classid',$classid);//If this is a must enter or not entered by user then you can use bindParam()
$stmt->bindValue(':userid',$userid);//This as well if this is a must enter then you can use bindParam()
if($firstname == "" || $firstname == NULL){
$stmt->bindValue(':firstname', NULL, PDO::PARAM_INT);//_NULL seems to give issues
}else{
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
}
$stmt->bindValue(':surname',$surname);
$stmt->bindValue(':form',$form);
$stmt->bindValue(':gender',$gender);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. I added an if isset statement before each line to see if that helped, but that caused the PHP to stop. I need to investigate further to see why.

Comment: This might help I think you have go through an `if ... else` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627400/sending-empty-values-with-pdo-results-in-error)

Comment: I updated the answer please check and let me know. You have to toggle the values.

Comment: It didn't work when I tried it, but I'm pretty tired so will call it quits for tonight and try tomorrow evening. Thank you all.

Comment: If you don't have null enabled it work you have enable null acceptance in you database columns.

Comment: Do I want a 'yes' or 'no' in the NULL column?

Comment: Just set default value as NULL in the column you want and see if it works tomorrow after you get some rest.

Comment: Thank you, setting to default NULL solved it. Reading some documentation it looks like this should only be necessary in strict mode, but I don't seem to be in strict mode. Anyway, it works, so thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Rob, this is not an answer to your question! I read your comments and I just wanted to show you how to properly use error reporting, prepared statements and exception handling.

You can structure the code in OOP or procedural functions, if you wish. But the structure is of no relevance here.

My advice: always read the documentation of the functions yu are using. Especially the returned values. This way you'll know how to properly handle all possible error-prone situations. In regard of PDO, this is a mandatory step ;-)

Good luck!

```
<?php

/*
 * Set error reporting level and display the errors on screen.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 * DON'T DISPLAY ERRORS ON PRODUCTION, DO IT ONLY ON DEVELOPMENT!
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    /*
     * Create a PDO instance as db connection.
     */

    // Create PDO instance.
    $connection = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=yourDb;charset=utf8'
            , 'yourDbUsername'
            , 'yourDbPassword'
    );

    // Assign driver options.
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE);

    /*
     * Prepare and validate the sql statement.
     * 
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() 
     * returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling settings).
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO students (
                classid,
                userid,
                firstname,
                surname,
                form,
                gender
            ) VALUES (
                :classid,
                :userid,
                :firstname,
                :surname,
                :form,
                :gender
            )';

    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

    if (!$statement) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('The sql statement could not be prepared!');
    }

    /*
     * Bind the input parameters to the prepared statement.
     * 
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), when using PDOStatement::bindParam() the variable 
     * is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that 
     * PDOStatement::execute() is called.
     * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    $bindings = array(
        ':classid' => $classid,
        ':userid' => $userid,
        ':firstname' => $firstname,
        ':surname' => $surname,
        ':form' => $form,
        ':gender' => $gender,
    );

    foreach ($bindings as $key => $value) {
        $bound = $statement->bindValue(
                getInputParameterName($key)
                , $value
                , getInputParameterDataType($value)
        );

        if (!$bound) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('An input parameter could not be bound!');
        }
    }

    /*
     * Execute the prepared statement.
     * 
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------
     * PDOStatement::execute returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    $executed = $statement->execute();

    if (!$executed) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('The prepared statement could not be executed!');
    }

    /*
     * Get last insert id.
     */
    $lastInsertId = $connection->lastInsertId();

    if (!isset($lastInsertId)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('The last insert id could not be read!');
    }

    /*
     * Close connection.
     */
    $connection = NULL;

    /*
     * Print results.
     */
    echo 'Provided data successfully added with the id: ' . $lastInsertId;
} catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
    echo $pdoException->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
    exit();
}

/**
 * Get the name of an input parameter by its key in the bindings array.
 *  
 * @param int|string $key The key of the input parameter in the bindings array.
 * @return int|string The name of the input parameter.
 */
function getInputParameterName($key) {
    return is_int($key) ? ($key + 1) : (':' . ltrim($key, ':'));
}

/**
 * Get the PDO::PARAM_* constant, e.g the data type of an input parameter, by its value.
 *  
 * @param mixed $value Value of the input parameter.
 * @return int The PDO::PARAM_* constant.
 */
function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}
```