# Doctrine : insert null value for date type in statement

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine

I'm not a big fan of Doctrine, but I need to use it for a specific project.
I have to migrate data from an old oracle database to a brand new postgresql database.

I use the query builder or raw queries with prepared statements. It's ok for most of the request, but I'm not ok with null values...

In the following request birthday can be null.

```
insert into public.mytable (id, name, birthday) values ('foo', 'bar', null);
```

I use bindValue, but Doctrine change the null into empty string, and Postgresql can't accept that...

That's how I try :

```
$rawQuery = "insert into public.mytable (id, name, birthday) values (:id, :name, :birthday);"
$statement = $pgsql->prepare($rawQuery);
$statement->bindValue('id', $id);
$statement->bindValue('name', $name);
$statement->bindValue('birthday', $birthday); // Can be null
$statement->execute();
```

It's fine if $birthday is not null, it crash otherwise.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure $birthday is null and not empty string? Also can you try $statement->bindValue('birthday', $birthday ?? null);

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! I tried with a null instead of the var.

Comment: Look at this topic, maybe it can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627400/sending-empty-values-with-pdo-results-in-error/13627845#13627845